# Restricting use of namespaces in MS Script Engine

Tags: c#, .net, windows, scripting, scriptengine

The .NET Framework has great features to support compiling code at runtime and running it, to achieve some kinds of scripting functionalities. There are already some scripting engines available on CodeProject, and Microsoft has its own library as well.

I am working on a web automation software, I want to include the Microsoft scripting engine in the application.

The problem is the scripting engines allow Using all namespace, in the referenced assembly, and I want to restrict the usage to a selected few namespace.

```
using System; // allowed.
using System.Linq; // allowed.
using System.Reflection; // restrict.
```

**How to restrict the use of namespaces, in the scripts.**

Comment: Can you access the code that is going to be compiled? (I mean the string representing the code)

Comment: So, which engine are you planning on using? The solution may depend on that.

Comment: do you want to restrict the use of namespaces OR of DLLs (like System.dll) ? the first is nearly not achievable if the "forbidden" namespace is in the same DLL as an "allowed" namespace... OR are you trying to do this as some sort of security measure (sandbox...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricting namespaces by name doesn't accomplish much since the extension can just include a copy of the class you don't like in its own assembly, but just renamed.

It sounds like what you really want is a security boundary. Put the extension in an untrusted AppDomain.